# CakePHP Find - Order By String-To-Int?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I want to use CakePHP to pull an array of photos from a database, sorted by photo title (0, 1, 2, 3...)  My query currently looks something like:

```
$ss_photos = $this->Asset->find('all',array(
  'conditions'=>array('kind'=>'photo'), 
  'order'=>'title'
));
```

Unfortunately the titles seem to be in string format, leading to an undesirable sort order (2.jpg after 19.jpg, etc).  Is there a quick way to cast 'title' as an int for ordering purposes within a Cake query of this type?

Comment: N.B. they are $ss_photos because they are destined for use in a slideshow, not because they depict Nazi "Schutzstaffel" members.  Sometimes it's important to make these things clear.

Comment: You can use [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) or `CONVERT()`

Comment: ORDER BY CAST(title AS INT) or similar would presumably work in MySQL, just pondering how best to integrate that into a CakePHP query!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is "recommended practice", but on a first pass it seems to work:

```
$ss_photos = $this->Asset->find('all',array(
    'conditions'=>array('kind'=>'photo'), 
    'order'=>'Asset.title + 0'
));
```

Any opinions?

Comment: 'order' => 'CAST(title AS INT)' also works well, BUT (I just discovered after deploying the code) only with MySQL 5.6 or equivalent. Use CAST AS SIGNED on older versions

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a hidden column which is responsible for orders in your example image names should be: 00002.jpg, 00019.jpg - this way the order will work properly.

If the results are not too many, I think it's easier to sort them in PHP (if you use it of course :)) See this [natsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) you just need to extract a list of images and to sort them.

Comment: Sorting in PHP could indeed be the least effort-intensive solution, if Cake is going to have trouble recasting the type during my query...