# Cakephp2 - natural sorting by strong with numbers

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have such query:

```
$a = $this->Gallery->find('all',array (
        'conditions'=>array('Gallery.id'=>$matches[1]),
        'contain' => array('Photo'=>array('fields'=>array('Photo.name'),
            'order'=>array('Photo.name'=>'ASC')
        ))));
```

This code gets galleries by id, and associated photos. I want to sort photos by name, and now i get for example this:

1.jpg
11.jpg
12.jpg
2.jpg

So, as You see, this is not natural sorting. I was looking for info, how can i archive this, but with no success. I guess, that i need to modify:

```
'order'=>array('Photo.name'=>'ASC')
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Can you show the database content? What are the names? If the names are as you've shown, it would only mean that it sorts just fine.

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771866/cakephp-find-order-by-string-to-int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will fully help your issue, but you can attempt to apply natural sorting of a MySQL database by sorting by length first:-

```
'order' => array(
    'LENGTH(Photo.name)' => 'ASC',
    'Photo.name' => 'ASC'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to try below code.

Just one difference. `'order'=>array('FIELD(Photo.name)'=>'ASC')`

```
     $a =   $this->Gallery->find('all',array (
            'conditions'=>array('Gallery.id'=>$matches[1]),
            'contain' => array(
                'Photo'=> array(
                    'fields'=>array('Photo.name'),
                    'order'=>array('FIELD(Photo.name)'=>'ASC')
                ),
                )
            )
        );
```

Hopefully It will work for you.
Let me know if you don't solve your issue.

Thanks.